# Enabling autocommit in PDO on a mysql with autocommit set to off

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've just been assigned to a legacy PHP codebase that worked without PDO.

Connections are done using this pattern:

```php
// Connect to MySQL Database
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
 
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

$con->autocommit(true);
```

And using that `autocommit(true)`, even though the MySQL server is configured with `SET autocommit = 0`, works as expected.

Now I'm trying to migrate queries from plain SQL to prepared statements, so I wrote this

```php
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, true);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 1);
```

and the following example function

```php
function updateTeam($pdo, $name, $id)
{
    try {
        $data = [
            'name' => $name,
            'id' => $id
        ];
        $sql = "UPDATE teams SET name = :name WHERE id=:id";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        // $pdo->commit();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        db::$pdo->rollback();
        error_log('Failed: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }
    catch (Exception $exc) {
        db::$pdo->rollback();
        error_log('Failed: ' . $exc->getMessage());
    }
}
```

doesn't commit. I have to uncomment the `$pdo->commit();` to make it work, which is something i do not want, because that will force me to change every single query at the app.

What am I missing on the PDO config?
I tried `var_dump($pdo->query('SELECT @@autocommit')->fetchAll());` and the result was

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["@@autocommit"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Comment: by the way, it is not necessary to migrate to PDO to use prepared statements, mysqli supports them as well

Comment: by the way, did you try to just execute `SET autocommit = 1`  as a regular query?

Comment: Unrelated, but why aren't you rethrowing the exceptions? Doesn't your code rely on these updates to succeed?

Comment: @Dharman this was just for the sake of example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO's autocommit is not the same as MySQL's autocommit. This means that if the value of `autocommit` is set to default to `0` in your MySQL config, it doesn't change the default value of `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT`. The default value of `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` is always `true`.

Changing the value of `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` to the same value or anything other than the bool or int is ignored. This means that both operations are no-op:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, true); // because the value by default is true
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 1); // converted to bool true, which is the same as the default
```

You can trick it by disabling and enabling the `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT`:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, true);
```

This will make two calls to MySQL server, which should set the MySQL's `autocommit` value to `1`.

Alternatively, you could just execute `SET autocommit = 1` to align the MySQL value with PDO's value.

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo->exec('SET autocommit = 1');
```